# How can I know the most frequent value from different users in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

A dataframe 'df' records the purchasing channels of different orders of users:

```
  user_id channel
0       a      TV
1       a      TV
2       a      TV
3       a     WEB
4       a     WEB
5       b     APP
6       b     APP
7       b      TV
8       b      TV
9       b     WEB
10      c     WEB
11      c     WEB
12      c     WEB
13      c      TV
14      c      TV
```

Now I want to know the most common channels diffent users used. The expected output should be:

```
  user_id frequent
0       a       TV
1       b      APP
2       c      WEB
```

If there are multiple results, choose the 1st one. For example, for user 'b', he has 2 orders from 'APP' and 2 from 'TV'. We choose 'APP' here

I also want the result combined with the original 'df' with transform (maybe):

```
  user_id channel frequent
0       a      TV       TV
1       a      TV       TV
2       a      TV       TV
3       a     WEB       TV
4       a     WEB       TV
5       b     APP      APP
6       b     APP      APP
7       b      TV      APP
8       b      TV      APP
9       b     WEB      APP
10      c     WEB      WEB
11      c     WEB      WEB
12      c     WEB      WEB
13      c      TV      WEB
14      c      TV      WEB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and selecting first value (if exist multiple first values):

```
df['frequent'] = df.groupby('user_id')['channel'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
print (df)
   user_id channel frequent
0        a      TV       TV
1        a      TV       TV
2        a      TV       TV
3        a     WEB       TV
4        a     WEB       TV
5        b     APP      APP
6        b     APP      APP
7        b      TV      APP
8        b      TV      APP
9        b     WEB      APP
10       c     WEB      WEB
11       c     WEB      WEB
12       c     WEB      WEB
13       c      TV      WEB
14       c      TV      WEB
```

Another solution with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['frequent'] = (df.groupby('user_id')['channel']
                    .transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]))
print (df)
   user_id channel frequent
0        a      TV       TV
1        a      TV       TV
2        a      TV       TV
3        a     WEB       TV
4        a     WEB       TV
5        b     APP      APP
6        b     APP      APP
7        b      TV      APP
8        b      TV      APP
9        b     WEB      APP
10       c     WEB      WEB
11       c     WEB      WEB
12       c     WEB      WEB
13       c      TV      WEB
14       c      TV      WEB
```

It seems there is difference between processing if multiple first values, `mode` dorting values, `value_counts` not:

```
df['frequent1'] = df.groupby('user_id')['channel'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
df['frequent2'] = df.groupby('user_id')['channel'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
print (df)
   user_id channel frequent1 frequent2
0        a      TV        TV        TV
1        a      TV        TV        TV
2        a      TV        TV        TV
3        a     WEB        TV        TV
4        a     WEB        TV        TV
5        b    ZAPP        TV      ZAPP <-changed data to APP
6        b    ZAPP        TV      ZAPP
7        b      TV        TV      ZAPP
8        b      TV        TV      ZAPP
9        b     WEB        TV      ZAPP
10       c     WEB       WEB       WEB
11       c     WEB       WEB       WEB
12       c     WEB       WEB       WEB
13       c      TV       WEB       WEB
14       c      TV       WEB       WEB
```